# C++ & SDL2 - "Auto-Generate" used DLLs?

Tags: c++, c, dll, sdl, sdl-2

I have this question for quite some time now and it's really annoying.

I'd like to know if there's some way to "auto-generate" the DLLs I used in my project on the executable folder(the "Debug" folder, to be specific).
I mean, the way I learned, every time I create a new project, I need to execute it first, so the "Debug" folder can be created, then I receive a error message saying that some DLLs are missing(like SDL2.dll), and then I copy/paste the missing DLLs from the libraries I used on this folder.

So, is there a way that, when executing my project for the first time, it creates the Debug folder AND the DLLs so I don't need to do it manually every single time? Also, is there a way to put them in another folder and the project still finds it, for organization's sake?(This way I can have the project folder and inside it only folders for the "resources" and the executable)

NOTE: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to make this work.

Instead of "auto-generating" the DLLs, there's a folder where it's possible to put them so Visual Studio(and maybe other programs, I don't know) can find them automatically, so you don't need to copy/paste it every time you create a new projet.

You just need to put the DLLs inside one of these folders:

`C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` if you're using a 32bit windows or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` if you're using a 64bit windows.

This way you only need to copy/paste the DLLs if you're on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the debug/release folder is created during build time ( compile and linking ).

If you want to change the "working directory" and, in other words, change the folder where the application is executed, you can do it from the Project Properties ( right click on solution explorer ) under Debug section.

Alternately you can specify a postbuild copy of your dll into the working directory.